# Count divs and show one

Tags: javascript

how can I count the divs with the same name and display only one and put a display on none of the others? this is the divs

```
<div class="add_icon">
I get 3 and I would like to count them and if there are 3 to display only one
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of them and:

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('add_icon')
let divs_count = divs.length
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean how can I display one. I make a condition if it is bigger than one display: none but how could I display one?

Comment: You can copy the first element, delete all these elements, and then create just one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('add_icon');
    for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  //Display the first div and hide the rest
   if(i == 0)
    divs[i].style.display = 'block';
   else
    divs[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
//Hide all divs
for(let i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll(".add_icon").length;i++)
{   document.querySelectorAll(".add_icon")[i].style.display = "none";
}
//Go back and show the very first one
document.querySelector(".add_icon").style.display = "block";
```

This will hide all the divs with the .add_icon clas and then go back and show the very first one.

You mentioned wanting the count, so if you want to use that for something, you can just do:

```
let divCount = document.querySelectorAll(".add_icon").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I count the divs with the same name

```
let icons = document.getElementsByClassName('add_icon')
let countIcons = icons.length-1;
```

> and display only one.

did you mean *display only one* the last or what?

```
icons[countIcons].style.display = 'block';
```

> and put a display on none of the others

```
    <style>
        .add_icon{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
```